# Returning success error message in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to redirect with a success/error message. I currently have this code, but in this instance it doesn't seem to display anything.

Controller:

```
return redirect()->action('Controller@index')->with('yes', 'Successfully subscribed');
```

View:

```
@if (Session::get('yes'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
     {{ Session::get('yes') }}
   </div>
@endif
@if (Session::get('no'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {{ Session::get('no') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Your code seems fine and should work. Is Controller@index calling the view with the block of code you have to display the session variable?

Comment: Yes, the index calls the view which contains the code to display session variable. The logic works accordingly as well but the message is not being displayed.

Comment: Perhaps this is a CSS issue, did you check the HTML output?

Comment: just use `session()` [laravel sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#using-the-session)

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara this worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    @if ($message = session()->has('yes'))
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
         {{ session()->get('yes') }}
       </div>
    @endif
    @if ($message = session()->has('no'))
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ session()->get('no') }}
      </div>
    @endif
```